# Lua string.match captures in a single variable?

Tags: lua

i want to remove separation characters from inbetween numbers in lua. For example: `19,300` -> `19300`.

I am able to extract the two "parts" of the number using

`a,b = string.match(amount, '(%d+),*(%d*)')`

but have to store the results in two separate variables first. I would like to have a clean way of storing all capture groups as a concatinated, single variable, instead of having to do `c=a..b` in an extra step. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: `a = amount:gsub(',','')`

Comment: `c = amount:gsub("%f[%D],%f[%d]", ""):match"%d+"`

Answer (score 2):

You can simply remove all non-digits: `local stripped = string.gsub( amount, '%D', '' )`.

Comment: thanks. I realize that this is the better solution to this problem, but i'm still curious; so there is no way to "group" capture groups in a single variable/line?

Comment: `local groupped = table.concat{ string.match( amount, '(%d+),*(%d*)' ) }`

Answer (score 1):

Yes the captures can be put into an array thusly:

`local res = { string.match(text, pattern) }`

The array `res` will contain the captures, and `#res > 0` can be used to determine if the match succeeded.